# Why Laravel4.2 Encryption Key less than Encryption Key character in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, encryption, laravel-4

I'm currently study Laravel4.2 and start to compared with Codeigniter 
But I found some problem on **Encryption Key** character as below code
I've used this key to testing in Laravel 4.2 but it don't work because I got messages 
**"mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm"**

But it's work perfect when I've used the same **Encryption Key** in **Codeigniter** latest version.

My question:How does Larave 4.2  secure if I used MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 of **Encryption Key**

- 'key' =>
  'SdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrdSdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrd',
- 'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,

Comment: You know your key is only about 50 chars repeated like 30 times? Why did you do that? Would have been better to be completely random

Comment: The Shift Exchange,

I don't wanna to do this and I also not yet understand and how should I choose type of Encrype Key for Laravel 4.2 that why I ask all expert and now Please could you recommend me to use it.
**Which one of character should I use for my encrypt right now?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES keys need to be indistinguishable from random and either 16, 24 or 32 bytes in length. It seems Laravel adds an additional check for the AES key to be a valid size.

Basically what the PHP's `mcrypt` does (not sure about the C-code) is that it extends the key data with `00` valued bytes if the key is smaller than 32 bytes, until it gets to the first legal AES key size. If the key is larger than 32 bytes it simply cuts it to 32 bytes. This is absolutely against any good practice with regards to handling keys.

So your AES key is likely just interpreted as `'SdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrd'`, encoded as ASCII. This *kind* of key certainly does not provide the full security of AES-256 as the key reduces the key space significantly (with slightly more than 8 bytes if a 62 character alphabet is used, assuming each value within the alphabet is equally likely).

And note that `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is *not* AES, so you will only be able to decrypt it with libraries that support Rijndael with a *block size* of 256.

Comment: Owlstead,

So I have to sued **SdRlCcZtE2ujlTZv5S3JZKN5bJvGQkrd** only and it may secure or possible for encrypt right?

Comment: Well, obviously *that* particular key is not secure anymore now you've posted it here. If the key was generated by a random number generator than it still has sufficient strength for AES-128 (which is pretty secure) but I would not all it AES-256 anymore. If you want to have a secure key, generate it with a random number generator and *if you need a string*, use hexadecimals to store the key value.